# printing all increasing subsequence using recursion

Tags: c++, algorithm, debugging, c++14

I'm trying to print all increasing subsequence with following.
But it is not working accordingly.

Please explain what actually my code doing.

I'm stuck since last 1 week.
But unable to figure out.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int temp[1000];
int ans = 1;
int cnt  = 0;

void solve(int *arr, int n, int k)
{
    if(k == n){
        cnt++;
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            cout<<temp[j]<<" ";
        }

        cout<<endl;
        return;
    }

    for(int i = k; i < n; ++i){
        if(arr[k] <= arr[i]){
            temp[k] = -2;
            solve(arr, n, i+1);
            temp[k] = 2;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {4, 1, 13, 7, 0, 2, 8, 11, 3};
    //int arr[] = {-1, 1 ,2, 3, 4};
    //int arr[] = {-1,1,2,3,4,11, 5,6, 2, 9};

    memset(temp, -1, sizeof(temp));

    solve(arr, 9, 0);
    cout<<cnt<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output should be total number of enumerating increasing subsequence.

Comment: You sure you need all? For example `[1, 2, 3]` would give `[[1], [2], [3], [1, 2], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]`. Or only ones that are not part of other subsequences?

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.  "It is not working" is not a problem specification.

Comment: When you update your post, include the output traces of intermediate values, and your opinions on where it begins to fail and how.  Include the expected and actual results.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/5910058)

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;` - Don't *ever* do that!

Comment: [1, 3,] also possible increasing sub sequence @krisz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This prints all increasing subsequences:

```
void print(const vector<int> v) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size() - 1; ++i)
    cout << v[i] << ", ";
  cout << v.back() << endl;
}

int solve(const vector<int>& v, size_t start, vector<int>& sequence) {
  print(sequence);
  int count = 1;
  for (size_t i = start; i < v.size(); ++i) {
    if (v[i] >= sequence.back()) {
      sequence.push_back(v[i]);
      count += solve(v, i + 1, sequence);
      sequence.pop_back();
    }
  }
  return count;
}

size_t solve(const vector<int>& v) {
  int count = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
    vector<int> sequence{v[i]};
    count += solve(v, i + 1, sequence);
  }  
  return count;
}
```

Usage:

```
vector<int> v{4, 1, 13, 7, 0, 2, 8, 11, 3};
auto count = solve(v);
cout << "Count: " << count << endl;
```

Output:

```
4
4, 13
4, 7
4, 7, 8
4, 7, 8, 11
4, 7, 11
4, 8
4, 8, 11
4, 11
1
1, 13
1, 7
1, 7, 8
1, 7, 8, 11
1, 7, 11
1, 2
1, 2, 8
1, 2, 8, 11
1, 2, 11
1, 2, 3
1, 8
1, 8, 11
1, 11
1, 3
13
7
7, 8
7, 8, 11
7, 11
0
0, 2
0, 2, 8
0, 2, 8, 11
0, 2, 11
0, 2, 3
0, 8
0, 8, 11
0, 11
0, 3
2
2, 8
2, 8, 11
2, 11
2, 3
8
8, 11
11
3
Count: 48
```

Comment: can i add arbitrary node at v[0] = INT_MIN and calling solve(v, 0 , sequence) from main with following modification for (size_t i = start; i < v.size(); ++i) { if (v[i] >= sequence.back()) { sequence.push_back(v[i+1]); count += solve(v, i + 1, sequence); sequence.pop_back(); } }

Comment: That would break stuff. You could add a `start` parameter to `solve(const vector<int>&)` or modify it to take a pair of iterators.